# How do I point two Tomcat instances at the same folder for static content?

Tags: tomcat, static, cluster-computing, mod-jk

Is there a recommended method of sharing static content such as PDF documents among two Tomcat instances running on the same server?

Background: I want to migrate our app server from a single instance of Tomcat to two instances, using mod_jk, so we can update WAR files on one while the other continues to serve users  (note: this is a single server and not a true cluster).

The issue we're encountering is how to ensure the ROOT webapp in both instances is pointing users to the *same* static content such as PDF files.   We've looked at using 'allowLinking' along with a symlink pointing both ROOT webapps to a shared content directory.

But some folks advise against using allowLinking for security reasons.  In addition, I've read that deleting/updating the WAR file will also delete the content on the symlink, which defeats the purpose of a having a single repository of static content outside the scope of the webapp/Tomcat instance.

Comment: Do you have to serve the static content via tomcat or can you have a subdomain such as static.example.com which holds and serves the static content?

Comment: @Robb  Apologies for the delay; I'm not getting emails from StackOverflow so I didn't realize a reply had been posted.   The static content doesn't need to be delivered by Tomcat, although it would be uploaded by Tomcat and put into the shared static subdomain folder.    I think I see how your suggestion would work (and not require allowLinking to be turned on).   Thanks,Steve